# Xcode Help : Unspecific error codes when creating custom classes in objective-c

Tags: xcode, macos, class, xcode6.1

I am reading a book about objective-c, this book is called "Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 2/e." This book talks about how to create custom classes. After following the tutorial and making sure my code exactly matched the books I continue to get an error from Xcode that says "Expected identifier or "(" ", this error appears twice. I tried everything inputing "{}" and "()" with no success. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error? Thanks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRPerson : NSObject

@property float _heightInMeters;
@property int _weightInKilos;

- (float)heightInMeters;
- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h;
- (int)weightInKilos;
- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w;

-(float)bodyMassIndex;
return _weightInKilos; / (_heightInMeters * _heightInMeters); 
// The error appears in the line above.
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put a `return` line of any kind in an `@interface` section. The `@interface` section is for declarations only. You've misread the book (or it has a misprint).

Comment: If you want to understand `@interface` and `@implementation`, read _my_ book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch04.html#_interface_and_implementation

Comment: Thanks so much! Have an amazing day. Only question how would I do this without return?

Comment: That code is code. It doesn't belong there. Just delete that line.